# Missing property after promisifying methods

Tags: typescript, promise, node-redis

I'm having problems with promisifying .get and .set Redis methods.

```
const getAsync: Promise<string> = promisify(client.get).bind(client)
const setAsync: Promise<void> = promisify(client.set).bind(client)
```

this gives the following error:

```
Type '(arg1: string) => Promise<string | null>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<string>': then, catch, finally, [Symbol.toStringTag]ts(2739)
```

How should I be doing this?

Comment: pls share reproducable example

Comment: They are indeed not promises, they're functions _returning_ promises. In the error message: `(arg1: string) => Promise<string | null>`, not `Promise<string>`.

Comment: Sounds like you're accessing a function that hasn't been invoked yet (the (arg1: string) => Promise<string | null> type) and expecting that it has been invoked already and resolved into a promise (the thing it returns)

Comment: If `promisify`'s types are right (and it seems likely they are), you can just remove the type annotation on `getAsync` and `setAsync`. Side note: `client.get` and `client.set` are **already** asynchronous, right? Just with the old-style callback API?

Comment: i actually think you would have better success with `promisify(client.get.bind.client)`